# Xcode 7.3.1 Objective-C .h file not found (it is in a framework not a podfile)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, header-files

This question seems to be a very basic one but I cannot find a solution on Stack Overflow or anywhere else that works for me so I am posting it here.

I have a .h file that is part of a framework - AWSCore/framework that the compiler states it cannot find.

[image: Import errors]

In the past I have tried using Cocoapods unsuccessfully and do not wish to suffer that pain again - I must use frameworks for this implementation.

I have added the framework to the project and you can see the framework toolbox icon in the Project Navigator:

[image: Project Navigator Image]

Opening the AWSCore Framework I can find the AWSCore.h:

[image: AWSCore Framework Image]

With AWSCore.h highlighted, Xcode shows the correct location of the framework and .h file when clicking the arrow in the File Inspector:

[image: File Inspector]

If I select the target, go to Build Phases > Link Binaries With Libraries, I can see the framework file there as well:

[image: Link Binary With Library Image]

Here is what I've tried:

1) Quit Xcode, start Xcode and clean project.

2) Quit Xcode, reboot.

3) Delete intermediate directories.

4) Select Target> Build Settings > Framework Search Paths > Debug > a non-recursive directory correctly points to where the framework resides.

5) Removed references to Framework and re-add Framework to project.

Additional information:

This project compiled and ran successfully yesterday.

I can archive it successfully with a distribution provisioning profile.

What have I missed?

Please do not recommend CocoaPods as a solution.